# dplyr exclude columns using the dot argument

Tags: r, dplyr

How can we write a function that let user drop multiple columns using the `...` argument `dplyr` style?

E.g.

```
mydrop=function(x,...){function body}
mydrop(npk,N:K)
```

returns `npk[,c("block","yield")]`.

Note that it is important that the `...` argument is compatible with all the `?select_helpers` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @akrun, but allowing for the `N:K` , dplyr style column selection the OP requested for (...), as well as some error handling:

```
mydrop <- function(x,...){
  try(
  todrop <- x %>%
    select(...) %>% names(.)
  , silent = TRUE)
  if(exists('todrop')){
    x %>% select(setdiff(current_vars(), todrop))
  }else x
}
```

Comment: You could also do `x %>% 
      select_if(!names(.) %in% names(select(x, ...)))`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we can use

```
mydrop <- function(x,...){
 nm <- list(...)

 if(length(nm)>0) {
  x %>%
    select(-one_of(unlist(nm)))

   } else x
}


mydrop(npk, "N", "K")
```

Using reproducible example

```
mydrop(mtcars, 'mpg', 'cyl') 
mydrop(mtcars)
mydrop(mtcars, names(mtcars)[-1])
mydrop(mtcars, names(mtcars))
```

Comment: What does one_of do exactly? ?one_of only says "one_of(..., vars = current_vars())"

Comment: @DougFir According to `?select_helpers`, one_of(): variables in character vector.

Comment: So it randomly chooses one of the variables in a list to select?

Comment: @DougFir   Based on the `...`, I guess the vars are selecting.  If you look at `everything(vars = current_vars())`, it is selecting all the variables

Comment: Oh.. so in that case why is it needed? Why not just select(...)?

Comment: @DougFir It won't work with `-`,  We are trying to drop those columns passed in the `...`

Comment: This doesn't work if (...) is empty, and it will give warnings if you select incorrect columns.  For example: `mydrop(mtcars)`

Comment: Just noticed it still doesn't work for the OP's original request: `mydrop(npk, N:K)`

Comment: @DavidKlotz  It is with the usage of `...`  Either that needs to change or have to use other ways.  I already showed ways to pass argumens with `names(mtcars)`